# Zuul Gateway Server , locallhost:5555/routes return 404 errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am trying to implement the `Zuul Gateway Service` in microservice architecture.

All the configuration files for services are located in git repository. The configuration for Zuul Gateway Server are located in gateway.properties file in git. Below it is the content:

```
#Application
#server.servlet.context-path=/
server.port=5555

#Eureka
cloud.config.enabled=true
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

#Gateway
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.security.enabled=false
```

The pom of Zuul Gateway Server is like below:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Below it the boostrap configuration files for Zuul Gateway Server :

```
spring.application.name=gateway
spring.profiles.active=default
cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

Below it is the boostrap class for the Zull Gateway Server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulServer
public class GatewayServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have tried to access the routes information with the following the urls:

- http://localhost:5555/routes
- http://localhost:5555/actuator/routes

But the result i got from these url is like below:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-03-30T17:12:21.326+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/actuator/routes"
}
```

When i try the url: http://localhost:5555/actuator
It shows the result below:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator",
            "templated": false
        },
        "archaius": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/archaius",
            "templated": false
        },
        "beans": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/beans",
            "templated": false
        },
        "caches-cache": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/caches/{cache}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "caches": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/caches",
            "templated": false
        },
        "health-path": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/health/{*path}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "health": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/health",
            "templated": false
        },
        "info": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/info",
            "templated": false
        },
        "conditions": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/conditions",
            "templated": false
        },
        "configprops": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/configprops",
            "templated": false
        },
        "env": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/env",
            "templated": false
        },
        "env-toMatch": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/env/{toMatch}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "loggers": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/loggers",
            "templated": false
        },
        "loggers-name": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/loggers/{name}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "heapdump": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/heapdump",
            "templated": false
        },
        "threaddump": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/threaddump",
            "templated": false
        },
        "metrics": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/metrics",
            "templated": false
        },
        "metrics-requiredMetricName": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/metrics/{requiredMetricName}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "scheduledtasks": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/scheduledtasks",
            "templated": false
        },
        "mappings": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/mappings",
            "templated": false
        },
        "refresh": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/refresh",
            "templated": false
        },
        "features": {
            "href": "http://localhost:5555/actuator/features",
            "templated": false
        }
    }
}
```

I will appreciate any hint, I have stuck here. 
Regarding the other services everything works very well. Configuration sever , eureka server and other services are working perfectly. |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: /actuator/routes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242507/spring-cloud-zuul-path-actuator-routes-404-not-found